# Generic Host logs are "late"

Tags: c#, .net

I started to look into Generic Host and its use in Console Apps. I have a simple Program.cs:

```cs
    internal class Program
    {
        private static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var builder = GetHostBuilder(args);
                await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Program run into an exception: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        private static IHostBuilder GetHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    //registartion of various services...
                    services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
                });
        }
    }
```

`MyHostedService` looks something like this:

```cs
public class MyHostedService : BackgroundService
{
    ILogger _logger;

    public MyHostedService(ILogger<MyHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger?.LogInformation("Starting MyHostedService");

        //Some work...
    }
}
```

When I run my application, I observe:

[image]

The logs coming from the host appear in the middle of the logs of `MyHostedService`, which is a bit strange. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The generic host doesn't handle logging, the logging subsystem does. You haven't configured it, so you only get console logging out of the box. There's nothing strange or slow either - when *multiple* threads log to the same target, the messages will be interleaved. Finally, the host starts only when you call RunConsoleAsync. When it does, it also starts all hosted services *before* editing the `Application Started` message.

Comment: BTW `_logger?.LogInformation("Starting MyHostedService");` is a synchronous call too, running on the main thread. The service will only start working asynchronously when it yields, eg in the first `await` or if it returns a Task

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok, I think I understand. So, to make logs look better, I added `await Task.Delay(1000)` in the beginning of `MyHostedService` execution. Yeah, I'm getting console logging, which is exactly what I need.